# Creation of torrent using monotorrent c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, bittorrent, monotorrent

I am trying to create a torrent for the files in my desktop using monotorrent i have tried like the below code

i am able to get the byte code i am not able to save it as torrent it shows access denied

```
enter code here  string path = "C:/Users/snovaspace12/Desktop/monotorrent-0.90/files";
        string savepath = "D:/results";

        TorrentCreator nnnn = new TorrentCreator();
        nnnn.CreateTorrent(path, savepath);

   public void CreateTorrent(string path, string savePath)
    {
        // The class used for creating the torrent
        TorrentCreator c = new TorrentCreator();

        // Add one tier which contains two trackers
        //RawTrackerTier tier = new RawTrackerTier();
        //tier.Add("http://localhost/announce");

        //c.Announces.Add(tier);
        c.Comment = "This is the comment";
        c.CreatedBy = "Doug using " + VersionInfo.ClientVersion;
        c.Publisher = "www.aaronsen.com";

        // Set the torrent as private so it will not use DHT or peer exchange
        // Generally you will not want to set this.
        c.Private = true;

        // Every time a piece has been hashed, this event will fire. It is an
        // asynchronous event, so you have to handle threading yourself.
        c.Hashed += delegate(object o, TorrentCreatorEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Current File is {0}% hashed", e.FileCompletion);
            Console.WriteLine("Overall {0}% hashed", e.OverallCompletion);
            Console.WriteLine("Total data to hash: {0}", e.OverallSize);
        };

        // ITorrentFileSource can be implemented to provide the TorrentCreator
        // with a list of files which will be added to the torrent metadata.
        // The default implementation takes a path to a single file or a path
        // to a directory. If the path is a directory, all files will be
        // recursively added


        ITorrentFileSource fileSource = new TorrentFileSource(path);

        // Create the torrent file and save it directly to the specified path
        // Different overloads of 'Create' can be used to save the data to a Stream
        // or just return it as a BEncodedDictionary (its native format) so it can be
        // processed in memory
        c.Create(fileSource, savePath);
    }
    public void Create(ITorrentFileSource fileSource, string savePath)
    {

        Check.SavePath(savePath);


        var file = Create(fileSource);//getting the fbyte code 
        File.WriteAllBytes( savePath, Create(fileSource).Encode()); //getting exception here 

    }
```

when i checked the byte code is returning properly to the file

it shows access is denied

Answer (score 2):

You’ve probably solved this already but I just encountered the same issue.  The solution, at least in my case, was pretty simple.

The problem originated with the **savePath** parameter in c.Create(fileSource, **savePath**);

I assumed **savePath** was a directory where the torrent would be saved.  It should be a file path instead.  For example **savePath**  = “C:\pathtomytorrents\content.torrent”

Hopefully that works for you!